# Performance between Java lib and C++ dll on Android

Tags: java, android, c++, performance, dll

I'm building an encryption application on Android.
Using library encrypt in Java.
But it's slowly during encrypt processing.

I think about using dll encrypt wrote by C++.

But does it actually make encrypt processing faster ?

If you have experience about that, please help me.

Comment: I don't have experience in Java or C++ on androids doing encryption so I'll just leave a comment, but I would assume that depending on the algorithm used, and the limited hardware resources of a mobile device, that C++ would provide a noticeable increase in performance. However, take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank u, I will take a look about that.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to tell this is by profiling.  C++ should be faster, but JNI overhead could slow it down.  So could bad programming.  Also note that faster isn't always better for encryption-  there are attacks on encryption implementations that are based on detecting that the programmer saw certain optimizations (such as not performing a calculation in 1 branch of an if statement) that lets it guess the values of certain keybits.  Take a well written, open source, debugged library over one that's faster.  And never write your own encryption unless you're an expert-  even if you write the algorithm perfectly you'll have side vector attacks like the one above in it.

Comment: So, I used Camellia in Java and Camellia in C++.
As u say, maybe JNI will make it slow.

Comment: I would expect the C++ to run faster.  But the way to tell is to do each 1000 times and time it (by getting the system time before and after the 1000 calls).  Whichever runs faster is your answer.